# Azure Lifecycle Management - Regions

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I've got an storage account in 'North Europe' and now I want to use the lifecycle management to move the cold blobs to archive tier.

But I everytime I try I get the following failure:
Failed to add a lifecycle management rule for storage account 'myStorrageAccount'. Error: ManagementPolicy rule MoveBackupToArchiv is invalid. Invalid value for parameter : baseBlob, tierToArchive is not supported in this region currently.

I checked all my data in the container and every file is on cold storage.

Comment: "Archive is not supported in this region" seems fairly clear, have you checked whether 'North Europe' supports archive tier?

Comment: @PeteKirkham...I thought so too. I just checked and archive tier is definitely supported for North Europe: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/services/?products=storage&regions=non-regional,europe-north,europe-west.

Comment: My guess is that the OP might be using this for an account type which doesn't support lifecycle management or there's an Azure Policy which is preventing that from happening.

Comment: Yes I checked it. @GauravMantri where can I check if my account doesn't support lifecycle management?

Comment: Please check the supported account types here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal#storage-account-support. You can check the type of your account in Azure Portal.

Comment: Ah ok, I've been using StorageV2 (general purpose v2)

Comment: Storage V2 account should have support for lifecycle management.

Comment: No other idea, why it doesn't work? :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The lifecycle management feature is available in all Azure regions.

This is a [bug](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/4580#issuecomment-547820540) in storage management policy.

This will only work in a region that supports `Move blob to cool storage`, `Move blob to archive storage` and `delete blob`. Not all regions support all 3 but attempts to apply them and gets an error back from Azure (correctly). North Europe is the region that has this issue.