# Add Lifecycle Management (tierToArchive) for Azure Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage

In my storageV2 I want to add lifecycle management.

1) Add rule for lifecycle management

2) Configuration

Name: Test, move blob to archive storage: Days: 5, Container selected: entire container

3) Validation passed

4) But I get the error: 
"Failed to add a lifecycle management rule
2:37 PM
Failed to add a lifecycle management rule for storage account 'Name of entity'. Error: tierToArchive is not supported for the account.."

The azure account is activated since today and I have a valid subscription.

Does anybody know, why I cannot move objects in the storage to archive tier? Or is there any other way to make use of archive pricing?

Thank you

Comment: Which type of storage account do you have? General purpose v1 or v2?

Comment: Account kind: StorageV2 (general purpose v2)

Comment: Location is: Germany West Central. I think this location was known before to have problems with storage tier. But as far as I can see. This is not the same problem like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59985935/azure-lifecycle-management-regions

Comment: Any chance you are using anything else as Locally Reduntant Storage (LRS) for replication? Any other option does not support the archive tier for block blobs at this moment.

Comment: I swiched from LRS to GRS and got exact same error. Do I have to wait until operation is finished? There is no progress indicator. Just says "Replication: Geo-redundant storage (GRS)" in the overview.

Comment: @tomas then that's not the issue. As I said only LRS supports archive tier. What happens if you just change a blob from hot to archive using the portal, does that work?

Comment: @404 I tested both LRS AND GRS, same error. Additionally I created a new blob configured as LRS. Switching between hot and cold worked. But adding lifecycle management here didn't work too. again. same error

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/353928/tiertoarchive-is-not-working-as-a-rule-and-also-ma.html "Archive storage is not currently available in the Germany region. This is anticipated to be available in Q2 2021. Please see the Azure products available by region for more information."